# NSObjectInaccessibleException - CoreData could not fulfill a fault

Tags: iphone, crash, core-data

My iPhone application crashes when and I do not know how to resolve it.

I have a secondary thread that does some cleanup (deletes objects). This cleanup is done on a  second NSManagedObjectContext as apple recommend when doing stuff in another thread. When the cleanup is finished I merge the two contexts.

My problem is that my application crashes when the tableview somehow tries to show a deleted object while the cleanup is running in the background.

Does anyone have a example or something that could show me a safe way to delete chunks of data in another thread without getting this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This was solved by removing [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20]; and disable caching!

Comment: Another solution is also to do a more specific fetch request, and exclude the objects that are going to be deleted before they are.